# Calculate the line integral where $F(x,y,z) = (\sin(x), \cos(y), xz)$, $r(t) = (t^3, -t^2, t)$ and $t\in[0,1]$

Tags: integration

Let
$$F(x,y,z) = (\sin(x), \cos(y), xz)\quad\text{and}\quad r(t) = (t^3, -t^2, t)$$
and $t$ from $0$ to $1$.

Then, how to find $ \int_{C} F\cdot\mathrm{d}r$ such that the curve $C$ is specified by the vector function $r$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, I don't have any idea, please give me an approach or hint on what to do?

Comment: You need to compute $\int_0^1 F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)\, dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(r(t))=(sin(t^3),cos(-t^2),t^4)$ , $r`(t)=(3t^2,-2t,1)dt \Rightarrow\int F \cdot dr=\int_0^1(3t^2sin(t^3)-2tcos(-t^2)+t^4)dt$

$\int_0^1(3t^2sin(t^3)-2tcos(-t^2)+t^4)dt=sin(-1)-cos(1)+2$